# How to remove special characters in a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Wondering how to take a string and remove special characters, make all characters lower-cased, but leave spaces intact.

Example: 
This: "Hello world! How are you?"
Would be this: hello world how are you

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share some code you wrote about this? If you can give more details about the specific issue that you have, then it would be easier for us to answer.

Comment: @Mark You need to write a corresponding function that will remove special characters.:)

Comment: So far I just have a program that reads the string for the user, and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it should also leave the spaces intact

Comment: Simply call the `gimme()` function with `fish` as parameter.

Comment: Check out  `tolower`, `isalpha` and their friends in ` <ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the isalpha() function like this:

```
void removeSpecialCharacter(char *str) {
  int source = 0; 
  int destination = 0; 

  while (str[source] != '\0') {
    if (isalpha(str[source])) {
      str[destination] = str[source];
      ++destination;
    }
    ++source;       }
  str[destination] = '\0';
}
```